# An application of Poincaré separation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be a square, positive-definite, symmetric matrix. Let

$$P = I - \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T$$

where $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector (of norm 1). Then $P$ is a projection matrix, projecting into the sub-space orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_N$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, and let $\rho_1,\rho_2,\dots,\rho_N$ be the eigenvalues of $PAP$. Assume these eigenvalues are sorted in descending order,

$$\alpha_1 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \dots \ge \alpha_N$$

$$\rho_1 \ge \rho_2 \ge \dots \ge \rho_N$$

Since $PAP$ is not full rank, $\rho_N=0$.

My question is whether Poincaré's separation applies in this setting, i.e., whether:

$$\alpha_1 \ge \rho_1 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \rho_2 \ge \dots \ge \rho_{N-1} \ge \alpha_N$$

I have checked numerically that the above chain of inequalities holds, for random $A,\mathbf{v}$.

Can someone help me prove it?

Comment: Is there some relationship between $A$ and $P$ that you forgot to mention? As it stands, you could take $A=2I$, in which case all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2$ which is larger than any eigenvalue of $P$.

Comment: @angryavian Oh sorry had a typo. The $\rho_i$ are the eigenvalues of $PAP$, not $P$. Corrected in the question.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3069216/10063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P=QQ^T$ where $Q^TQ = I_{n-1}$

Then $PAP = QQ^T AQQ^T = Q\big(Q^T AQQ^T\big)$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as  $\big(Q^T AQQ^T\big)Q=Q^T AQ\big(Q^TQ\big) =Q^T AQI_{n-1} = Q^T AQ$

$\alpha_1 \ge \rho_1 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \rho_2 \ge \dots \ge \rho_{N-1} \ge \alpha_N\gt 0$
then holds by Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing

Comment: Can you define $Q$ explicitly?

Comment: use diagonalization: $P=VDV^{T} = VD^2V^{T}= \big(VD\big)\big(VD\big)^T=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \mathbf v_k\mathbf v_k^T= QQ^T$ where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is diagonal with $n-1$ oness and $d_{n,n}=0$.  So $\mathbf q_k := \mathbf v_k$.